# Query to extract results using null values or not equal to

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query like this

```
SELECT s.admission_number, s.student_name, c.class, m.month, 
       f.fee, fr23.amount_received
FROM students s
LEFT JOIN fee_receipts fr ON s.id = fr.admission_number
LEFT JOIN fee_receipts_23_repeat fr23 ON fr.id = fr23.parent_id
JOIN class c ON s.class = c.id
LEFT JOIN fee f ON f.id = fr23.fee
LEFT JOIN months m ON m.id = fr23.month
```

which shows the result like this?

```
ad_num  student_name class   month    fee   amount_received 
779     A Jain      Nur     January Tuition   Fee   575.00
808     A Gupta     Nur     January Tuition   Fee   0.00
821     A Mohanty   Nur     NULL    NULL            NULL
818     ATiwari     Nur     FebruaryTuition   Fee   575.00
826     D Mishra    Nur     NULL    NULL      NULL
813     G Kaur      Nur     NULL    NULL      NULL  NULL
809     P Palai     Nur     NULL    NULL      NULL
822     S Agrawal   KG1     December Tuition  Fee   575.00
773     S Garg      KG1     NULL    NULL            NULL
```

Now I am trying to get the list of students by class, who has not paid the fee, by excluding those who have paid, but not getting the correct result. The conditions I am adding to the above query is like this

```
where fr23.amount_received is NULL and c.class = 'Nur' and m.month != 'January'
```

I expect the result that it will list all students, who have not paid for January, but it is giving me an empty result set.

Actually I am trying to find the students for whom there is no entry for payment is made, which means the column month, fee and amount_received will have null values.

I am not very sure if I am taking the correct approach?

Comment: Can you maybe use the four spaces and backticks to indicate code and output in your question, so that it's all a bit more readable?

Comment: When you said `the column month, fee and amount_received will have null values.`, have you tried `where m.month is NULL and f.fee is NULL and fr23.amount_received is NULL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your condition into the `JOIN ON` condition:

```
SELECT s.admission_number, s.student_name, c.class, m.month, 
       f.fee, fr23.amount_received
FROM students s
LEFT JOIN fee_receipts fr ON s.id = fr.admission_number
LEFT JOIN fee_receipts_23_repeat fr23 ON fr.id = fr23.parent_id
    AND fr23.amount_received is NULL   -- Moved to here
JOIN class c ON s.class = c.id
LEFT JOIN fee f ON f.id = fr23.fee
LEFT JOIN months m ON m.id = fr23.month
    AND (m.month != 'January' OR m.month IS NULL) -- Added IS NULL check
```

Comment: Why are you checking for month *not* equal to January?

Comment: Sorry, looks like there is some problem, the query is including the students who have paid for the Month of January and value of either January, month or amount_received is not null.

Comment: bogus answer - the placement of the condition didn't fix the problem.  adding the null check did.  and you are actually changing the nature of the query.  going forward that clause will not belong there

Comment: @ Bohemian I need report for all months. January is just one example. I am including month not equal to January means, if a student have paid for January, it will hold the value January and exclude from the list of unpaid students.

Comment: exactly my point.  you will want to use the coalesce(m.month,'') in a group by clause to get the report you want.

Comment: I have to move it back in the last with the where clause to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

classic null trap!

null comparisons do not act as you might think...

```
change m.month != 'January'

to

coalesce(m.month,'') != 'January'
```

Comment: I have tried coalesce(m.month,'') != 'January', but the result is including the students who have paid.

Comment: ok - i'll write your query for you...  initially, i was just pointing out the conceptual error you had and was going to let you figure out the rest

Comment: Ok adding the where clause now, is excluding the students who have paid. is there any way where the month can be supplied as a parameter. I am using Fabrik Joomla Addon for mysql interface. Since the view I create will have no values for month, the filter I create on this field won't show any months and even if it shows is of no value, as there is no filter such as != and so I have to create twelve views for twelve months.

Comment: i think you are better off creating a result set that lists the student, class, month, owed, paid, balance.  then you can use that same resultset for multiple queries where you specify what you want.  you'd be in effect flattening your data to a iew that is easy/intuitie to query

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try in that direction.